# how can i apply blob extraction on an edge image?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection, blobs

I have an edge image and I want to do Blob (object) detection , i have tried do typical blob analysis with CvBlob but the result is poor(i'm working with OPENCV )
here is an example of and input image.
http://postimg.org/image/6uvzhdqad/

Comment: If you want to do object detection, why do you use blobs? can you upload the original image?

Comment: By Blob (object) detection i mean finding bouding box of the edge object here is the image http://s26.postimg.org/hhpsmsyft/edgecont.jpg

Comment: Bit of preprocessing like median filtering and morphological filtering might improve your results

Comment: one erosion followed by a dilation should remove most of the noise.

Answer (score 0):

To improve your results, you could try:

1. low pass filtering (Gaussian or median) the image before edge detection
2. morphological operations (erosion, dilation, open, close) after binarizing
3. Removing certain blobs by their size, shape etc.

However, none of these can guarantee very accurate object detection. Other possible approaches are:

1. If you have an image/s of the scene without objects, you can use background subtraction
2. If you know characteristics/features of objects, you can use segmentation or object recognition using those features.

Comment: well that's the problem Totoro I'm using an edge based background Subtraction and that is the result which i want to improve